# How to run a Matlab script/m-file through batch file on system startup?

Tags: matlab, batch-file, automation, startupscript

I've got a Matlab script which needs to be run every time the system reboots. I've got the Matlab setup on a system server. The system reboots every week (On Sunday, but not specific to any time period).

Can I run the m-file every time the system reboots?

Comment: Call your MATLAB script from `startup.m`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to it. But should I write a call statement in the startup.m?
Also, where can I find startup.m?

Comment: See http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html, but you should really learn the MATLAB basics first, see the tutorials at https://uk.mathworks.com/support/learn-with-matlab-tutorials.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can run any matlab script from the terminal using the command

```
matlab -nodisplay myfile.m
```

So if you include that line in a batch script, which your system runs at startup, it should be run every time your system reboots.

Comment: I'm new to MATLAB, sorry but it would sound a little amateur.  How do I change the directory to wherever the m-file is located?
Should I also place the batch file in the same folder?

Comment: In batch you change the directory by using the command `cd *directory*`. If I were to do what you are doing I would probably change the directory to the one where the matlab scribt is located, run it using the above command, then change back again.